# index of nested div with click event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that I'm using trying to get the index of the outermost parent div but can't seem to return it.

Here is the list of several divs:

```
<div class="owl-item">
  <div class="icon-holder-selection" id="sel11">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="cur11">
      <img src="images/icons/11.jpg">
        <div class="icon-action">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-selection" id="11"></span>
          <span class="icon-content">Remove</span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div class="icon-holder-selection" id="sel12">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="cur12">
      <img src="images/icons/12.jpg">
        <div class="icon-action">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-selection" id="12"></span>
          <span class="icon-content">Remove</span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div class="icon-holder-selection" id="sel13">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="cur13">
      <img src="images/icons/13.jpg">
        <div class="icon-action">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-selection" id="13"></span>
          <span class="icon-content">Remove</span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My click event looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-selection", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault ();

    //var index = $(this).index();

    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var index = $(".owl-item").index(parent);

    console.log("INDEX: " + index);

});
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: the closest `div` on those clicks will be one with an `.icon-action` class, not any of the `.owl-item` divs, so it won't be in the `$('.owl-item')` list. Try `$(this).closest('.owl-item')`

Comment: ah..I should have caught that, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a class name `.owl-item` for the div in `.closest()`, otherwise it will just return a direct parent of your `span` element.

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/1t6xgbth/

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-selection", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault ();

    //var index = $(this).index();

    var parent = $(this).closest('div.owl-item');
    var index = $(".owl-item").index(parent);

    alert(index);
    console.log("INDEX: " + index);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using delegateTarget is easier and simpler by using the owl-item selector instead of document:

```
$('.owl-item').on("click", ".remove-selection", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault ();

     console.log($(e.delegateTarget).index());

});
```

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90nzh6tn/)